# kubectl pipe watch changes to individual files via bash script

Tags: bash, kubernetes, pipe

**NOTE**: this is I think a bash question, not kubernetes or kubectl

I can run the following:

```bash
kubectl get pods -n myspace -w
```

which will "watch" and provide a stream of lines with e.g. pod name, ready count, status, restarts, and age

similarly I can run

```bash
kubectl get pods -n myspace -w -o json
```

which will provide more fine-grained change info.  I note that the end of a json block appears to be an unindented `}` and an unindented `{` next begins the following block.

my question is, how could I pipe the above to write individual files based on either a new line, or an unindented `{`?

If there *is* a native kubernetes way to do that that *does not* involve extensions or plugins this would be a viable solution though I would prefer a pure bash command-line solution.

Comment: Why must it be a shell script; do you have an option of using a Kubernetes SDK in some higher-level language?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'd be open to a tool like this in Go, Python or (maybe) PHP, yes.  The ultimate goal is to get the data deltas as events in a database on pods or resources.

Comment: The Kubernetes documentation has a list of [Client Libraries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/).  The API equivalent of `kubectl get -w` will be called "watch".

Answer (score 1):

You could convert each object into a single line json object with `jq`:

```
i=0;
while read line; do
  i=$(($i+1)) 
  echo "$line" > "$i.json"
done < <(kubectl get pods -w -o json | jq -rc '.')
```

Comment: `./test-file: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token '<'
./test-file: line 5: 'done < <(kubectl get pods -w -o json | jq -rc '.')'`
-- not working

Comment: i tested this using bash on debian and mac, as well as ash on alpine. it works.